# PayPal MassPay API

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox, masspay

I just bought a script with the Masspay API needed to make an authorized payment at a specific time the "deal" ends.

With that said I am unclear why mass pay would need to be enabled for this feature.

If someone could please explain what Masspay is? And I have been reading that masspay is no longer availabe and I would have to contact paypal directly? Is this true for the sandbox accounts also?

If anyone has any information on this subject I am more than thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: MassPay is a way to send payments from your account out to other accounts.  Is that what you're trying to do, or are you trying authorize payments to your own account that you will then capture when the deal ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your correctly,

- [Mass Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/) is used for sending money.
- If you are the merchant with record (you ship items and charge customers), then [PayPal Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#ec) is what you want. You can **DoAuthorization** to hold the fund before you ship the item, and then **DoCapture** to collect payment after you shipped.
- In you are part of the service provider, say you and another merchant both provide the service and own the payment from customer, then [Adaptive Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#adaptive) is what you need. You need call  **Pay** after you shipped.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms Masspay allows you to make multiple payments to multiple people in a single shot using xls or csv files.

No, paypal is not sun-setting Masspay. This feature is still available and will be supported by Paypal.